# How to avoid keys with zero percentage in pie plot matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have to plot pie chart with %age values, I am facing a problem that some value are very small and their %age is about zero, when I plot using matplotlib in python, therir labels overlab and they are not readable. I think its one solution is to avoid values with zero %age and second is to seprate labels to overlap (with some arrow etc.) Here is my simple code

```
def show_pi_chart(plot_title,keys,values,save_file):
    size = len(keys)
    #Get Colors list
    color_list = make_color_list(size)
    pyplot.axis("equal")
    pyplot.pie(values,
               labels=keys,
               colors=color_list,
               autopct="%1.1f%%"
               )
    pyplot.title(plot_title)  
    pyplot.show()
```

And my chart is
[image]

What is the solution to make labels dictant or remove small %age keys

Comment: should we mention that pie charts are evil?

Comment: Its better to ask simple question rather than devoting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work as intended:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np

def fixOverLappingText(text):

    # if undetected overlaps reduce sigFigures to 1
    sigFigures = 2
    positions = [(round(item.get_position()[1],sigFigures), item) for item in text]

    overLapping = Counter((item[0] for item in positions))
    overLapping = [key for key, value in overLapping.items() if value >= 2]

    for key in overLapping:
        textObjects = [text for position, text in positions if position == key]

        if textObjects:

            # If bigger font size scale will need increasing
            scale = 0.05

            spacings = np.linspace(0,scale*len(textObjects),len(textObjects))

            for shift, textObject in zip(spacings,textObjects):
                textObject.set_y(key + shift)


def show_pi_chart(plot_title,keys,values):

    pyplot.axis("equal")

    # make sure to assign text variable to index [1] of return values
    text = pyplot.pie(values, labels=keys, autopct="%1.1f%%")[1]

    fixOverLappingText(text)
    pyplot.title(plot_title)

    pyplot.show()


show_pi_chart("TITLE",("One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven", "Eight"),(20,0,0,10,44,0,0,44))
```

[image]